# Spark Java except method vs. leftanti join returning inconsistent results, possible bug?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

There seems to be a bug that I've encountered in the Spark dataframes Java API. I'm Using spark 2.3.1. I'd been scratching my head for days and I couldn't figure out the reason why the result would be different between the 2 approaches for filtering out unwanted data using except vs. leftanti.

**It seems that the except function actually is a except distinct! The dataframe that except is invoked on is removed of any duplicates!**

Just wanted to provide this information incase anyone else runs into the same issue! Running the except function results in unique data in the resulting dataframe. To preserve the original data, make sure to use leftanti!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that `.except()` acts as `EXCEPT DISTINCT` operation as of [2.3.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#except-org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset-). The previous documentations where `EXCEPT` is mentioned are incorrect as the behaviour was always `EXCEPT DISTINCT`

If you compare plans of `leftanti`

```
== Physical Plan ==
*BroadcastHashJoin [value#1], [value#4], LeftAnti, BuildRight
:- LocalTableScan [value#1]
+- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]))
   +- LocalTableScan [value#4]
```

And the `except()`:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*HashAggregate(keys=[value#1], functions=[])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(value#1, 200)
   +- *HashAggregate(keys=[value#1], functions=[])
      +- *BroadcastHashJoin [coalesce(value#1, )], [coalesce(value#4, )], LeftAnti, BuildRight, (value#1 <=> value#4)
         :- LocalTableScan [value#1]
         +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(coalesce(input[0, string, true], )))
            +- LocalTableScan [value#4]
```

You can see that there is additional `HashAggregate` step which removes duplicates.

Comment: You are right! I tested this. the except function actually removes all duplicates from the final dataframe!